# Why does this method return an unprintable character, how do I convert it to display correctly?

Tags: c, terminal

[Page 14](http://www.hth.com/filelibrary/pdffiles/snap.pdf) says that the method should return the value 'h17'

```
typedef struct  {
  uint8_t data;
  uint8_t timestamp;
  unsigned char crc;
} tData;


int main(void)
{
  unsigned char* tempData = "snap";

    for(;;)
    {
      tData payload;
      payload.crc = crc8(tempData,sizeof(tempData));
      UDR0 = payload.crc;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because “h17” is an unprintable character, namely ASCII ETB. The 'h' in “h17” stands for “hexadecimal”, like the `0x` usually used in C.

You should convert the value to an ASCII number if you want to print it, using for example `Serial.print(payload.crc, 16);` or – if you are not using Arduino core – `(s)printf()`.

---

**Edit**: here is an implementation of my comment “*sprintf() into a
buffer and dump the buffer to UDR0 one byte at a time*”:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void print_byte_in_hex(uint8_t byte)
{
    // Print the byte in ASCII into an internal buffer.
    char buffer[8];
    sprintf(buffer, "%02x\r\n", byte);

    // Send it one byte at a time through the USART.
    for (char * p = buffer; *p; p++) {
        loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSR0A, UDRE0);
        UDR0 = *p;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not using Arduino core in this instance. What is (s)? So something like: UDR0 = printf(payload.crc)

Comment: @SensationSama: I mean you either `sprintf()` into a buffer and dump the buffer to UDR0 one byte at a time, or you [set up stdin to print through the serial port](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html#details) and then do something like `printf("%02x\n", (unsigned int) payload.crc)`.

Comment: Okay great. Can you spoon feed me the buffer process a bit?

Comment: @SensationSama: done in the edit, but not tested.

Comment: Thanks, seems to work perfectly! One last follow-up question. If h17 is hexadecimal, and the decimal equivalent is 23, than why is my terminal printing 99?

Comment: @SensationSama: Hard to say without seeing the whole program. What does it print if you `print_byte_in_hex(0x17)`?

Comment: You're able to see all the code that is interacting here. That parameter results in a print of 17.